# How to get a common legend for stacked geom_bar and geom_point in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

So I'm constructing a graph with the following information:

- The income components of a *single household* (wage, social transfers, taxes), displayed in a stacked geom_bar chart and divided by *country*;
- The *net income* of each household-country after taxes and transfers, displayed in a geom_point chart.

This is arranged in the following data frame:

```
example <- data.frame(country = c("Arcadia", "Asgard", "Atlantis", "Avalon"),
            wage = c(80, 70, 55, 40),
            transfers = c(15, 15, 5, 20),
            tax = c(-10, -5, -5, 0),
            net = c(85, 80, 65, 60)) %>% gather(icom, euro, wage:net)
```

It is then graphed thus:

```
income_graph <- ggplot(filter(example, icom != "net"), aes(x = country, y = euro, fill = factor(icom, levels = c("transfers", "wage", "tax")))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") +
  geom_point(data = filter(example, icom == "net"), colour = "black", shape = 5) +
  labs(fill = "Income components") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys", labels=(c("Social transfers", "Wage", "Tax"))) 
income_graph
```

This results in the the following graph.

[image]

This is where I need assistance: the graph does what I need it to do, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the geom_bar and geom_point graphs to use a combined legend (i.e. the round "net" indicator under the same "Income components" heading). From what I'd found reading other entries a solution might be to map both the geom_bar and geom_point to "fill", but that just seems to end up with the "net" diamond overlapping the other icom entries.[*]

Thanks in advance, and hope the question isn't a duplicate -- I could not find an applicable solution on StackOverflow, but will happily be redirected to one if the answer is obvious.

LS

[*] = (Separately, and on a much smaller scale, is it possible to get the "net" indicators to be filled white and with a black outline? This probably has a logical solution but I find myself scratching my head at it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geom_point(shape=21) + scale_color_manual` is a life-saver for this kind of cases

```
income_graph <- ggplot(filter(example, icom != "net"), aes(x = country,
 y = euro, fill = factor(icom, levels = c("transfers", "wage", "tax",'net')))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") +
  geom_point(data = filter(example, icom == "net"),aes(color=icom), 
  shape = 21, size = 1.5, stroke = 1,fill='white') +
  labs(fill = "Income components") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys", labels=(c("Social transfers", "Wage", "Tax"))) +
  scale_colour_manual("", values='black', label='Net')
income_graph
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I moved the fill aesthetic to the bar, by leaving it in the ggplot call it tries to apply this to all of the geoms. I've added to the geom_point call an aesthetic that maps the shape to the icom column, and mapped this later on with scale_shape_manual.

Hopefully this is what you want!

```
income_graph <- ggplot(filter(example, icom != "net"),
                       aes(x = country, y = euro)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(icom, levels = c("transfers", "wage", "tax"))),
           stat = "identity", colour = "black") +
  geom_point(data = filter(example, icom == "net"),
             aes(shape = icom),
             colour = "black") +
  labs(fill = "Income components", shape = "") +
  guides(shape = guide_legend(order = 2),
         fill = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys", labels=(c("Social transfers", "Wage", "Tax"))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("net" = 5), labels="Net")
income_graph
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5qOd.png)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed solved the layout problems -- couldn't get it to work in combination with the other provided solution on filling the round dots though. But in combination (I've got many graphs, and the problems in the above one are not always present all at the same time) the solutions indeed sort it.